# Loading different xib for iPhone 5 fails

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make my app detect if the user is on a iPhone 5 screen or not.

I'm successfully using the following method in other views.

Via a button I call the Xib / view to be loaded

```
- (IBAction)DemoTapeTwo:(id)sender {

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    DemoTapeTwoViewController *Second = [[DemoTapeTwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:Second animated:YES completion:NULL];

} else {
    DemoTapeTwoViewController *Second = [[DemoTapeTwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoTapeTwoViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:Second animated:YES completion:NULL];


 }
```

I have two xib's,

iPhone 5 one : XViewController_568.xib

iPhone 4 one : XViewController.xib

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
    nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_568", nibName];
}
if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {

}
return self;
}
```

This ^ goes in the .m file

It should detect if the screen is a iPhone 5 or iPhone 4 screen and adjust the Xib to it.

However, Xcode errors out :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /Users/SamGuichelaar/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/321B4512-7BD3-46D8-A944-F12029448326/Parkway Drive Gestures.app (loaded)' with name '(null)_568''
First throw call stack:

So, something goes wrong making it not find the original name of the iPhone 4 Xib.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's clear from your exception message that your initWithNibName:bundle: method is being called with nil arguments - hence "(null)_568"

Comment: But it works on another project perfectly. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I guess you're calling the method manually in that other project? How about here, where and how do you instantiate this view controller?

Comment: In your first if condition it looks like you're passing `nil` as the nib name. What happens if you change it to [[DemoTapeTwoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DemoTapeTwoViewController" bundle:nil];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest checking to see if nibName is nil and if so using the class name.

I like to use the [`?:`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Conditionals.html) for this kind of quick substitution.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
        nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_568", nibName ?: @"DemoTapeTwoViewController"];
    }

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

---

To make it more generic, use [NSStringFromClass()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromClass).

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    if ([[ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 ) {
        nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_568", nibName ?: NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    }

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {

    }
    return self;
}
```